# how to input chart into value format, not percent format

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Desktop Search Engine Market Share - 2016"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        startAngle: 240,
        yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
        indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
        dataPoints: [
            {y: 79.45, label: "Google"},
            {y: 7.31, label: "Bing"},
            {y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"},
            {y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"},
            {y: 1.26, label: "Others"}
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

so i have this syntax, but when appear, it become percent for the value, how to transform the format become the values itself, not percent format (%)

Comment: What do you mean? Those *are* percentages. What values do you want to show instead?

Comment: yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"" has '%' in it.. You want to remove it?

Comment: yes if i input the values "79,45" it means that 79,45, not 79,45 percent, so if the chart appear, the values of 79,45 is not 79,45 %

Comment: @rolandruul yes i mean i want to insert the values of the frequency, not the exact percent, which part i should change so the chart appear with values and convert itself to percent, so if there's 150 of total, and i input 75, it become 50 percent, not 75 percent

Comment: The data is hardcoded at the moment, so where should it actually come from? Where's the total?

Comment: i want the system count itself, so if i input 75 and 30 and 45, it means the total was 150, so the chart appear in 75 (50 percent), 30 (20 percent), and 45 (30 percent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the y-value being shown in toolTip by setting yValueFormatString. Removing yValueFormatString from the code should should according to your requirements.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
      text: "Desktop Search Engine Market Share - 2016"
  },
  data: [{
      type: "pie",
      startAngle: 240,
      //yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
      indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
      dataPoints: [
          {y: 79.45, label: "Google"},
          {y: 7.31, label: "Bing"},
          {y: 7.06, label: "Baidu"},
          {y: 4.91, label: "Yahoo"},
          {y: 1.26, label: "Others"}
      ]
  }]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
```